# Saving data to default asp.net database

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net

i have a multiple choice quiz where a user will perform the quiz and will returned with a result based on their entries, i need to be able to save this score to a database alongside the name of the test that they took (My website has more than 1). I need to create a new table in my database and link it to my users table so i can save which user has scored what in each test.
The only thing is, im not sure how to access and manipulate the default database or how to create new tables with SQL. Can someone show me how to do this or possibly point me in the right direction as i am very new to using asp and coding in general. Below are the current states of the pages:

Test code:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

    <asp:Label ID="QLabel1" runat="server" Text="Question 1"></asp:Label>
    <asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList1" runat="server"
        RepeatDirection="Horizontal" RepeatLayout="Table">
        <asp:ListItem Text="*Answer 1*" Value="Incorrect 1" />
        <asp:ListItem Text="*Answer 2*" Value="Correct" />
        <asp:ListItem Text="*Answer 3*" Value="I" />
        <asp:ListItem Text="*Answer 4*" Value="4" />
    </asp:RadioButtonList>
    <div>
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="Q1requiredvalidator" runat="server" Display="Dynamic" ControlToValidate="RadioButtonList1" CssClass="text-danger" EnableClientScript="True" ErrorMessage="Ensure question 1 is completed"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
    </div>

    <asp:Label ID="QLabel2" runat="server" Text="Question 2"></asp:Label>
    <asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList2" runat="server"
        RepeatDirection="Horizontal" RepeatLayout="Table">
        <asp:ListItem Text="*Answer 1*" Value="Incorrect 1" />
        <asp:ListItem Text="*Answer 2*" Value="Correct" />
        <asp:ListItem Text="*Answer 3*" Value="I" />
        <asp:ListItem Text="*Answer 4*" Value="4" />
    </asp:RadioButtonList>
    <div>
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="Q2requiredvalidator" runat="server" Display="Dynamic" ControlToValidate="RadioButtonList2" CssClass="text-danger" EnableClientScript="True" ErrorMessage="Ensure question 2 is completed"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
    </div>

    <asp:Label ID="QLabel3" runat="server" Text="Question 3"></asp:Label>
    <asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList3" runat="server"
        RepeatDirection="Horizontal" RepeatLayout="Table">
        <asp:ListItem Text="*Answer 1*" Value="Incorrect 1" />
        <asp:ListItem Text="*Answer 2*" Value="Correct" />
        <asp:ListItem Text="*Answer 3*" Value="I" />
        <asp:ListItem Text="*Answer 4*" Value="4" />
    </asp:RadioButtonList>
    <div>
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="Q3requiredvalidator" runat="server" Display="Dynamic" ControlToValidate="RadioButtonList3" CssClass="text-danger" EnableClientScript="True" ErrorMessage="Ensure question 3 is completed"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
    </div>
    <asp:Label ID="QLabel4" runat="server" Text="Question 4"></asp:Label>
    <asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList4" runat="server"
        RepeatDirection="Horizontal" RepeatLayout="Table">
        <asp:ListItem Text="*Answer 1*" Value="Incorrect 1" />
        <asp:ListItem Text="*Answer 2*" Value="Correct" />
        <asp:ListItem Text="*Answer 3*" Value="I" />
        <asp:ListItem Text="*Answer 4*" Value="4" />
    </asp:RadioButtonList>
    <div>
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="Q4requiredvalidator" runat="server" Display="Dynamic" ControlToValidate="RadioButtonList4" CssClass="text-danger" EnableClientScript="True" ErrorMessage="Ensure question 4 is completed"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
    </div>
    <asp:Label ID="QLabel5" runat="server" Text="Question 5"></asp:Label>
    <asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList5" runat="server"
        RepeatDirection="Horizontal" RepeatLayout="Table">
        <asp:ListItem Text="*Answer 1*" Value="Incorrect 1" />
        <asp:ListItem Text="*Answer 2*" Value="Correct" />
        <asp:ListItem Text="*Answer 3*" Value="I" />
        <asp:ListItem Text="*Answer 4*" Value="4" />
    </asp:RadioButtonList>
    <div>
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="Q5requiredvalidator" runat="server" Display="Dynamic" ControlToValidate="RadioButtonList5" CssClass="text-danger" EnableClientScript="True" ErrorMessage="Ensure question 5 is completed"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
    </div>
    <asp:Label ID="QLabel6" runat="server" Text="Question 6"></asp:Label>
    <asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList6" runat="server"
        RepeatDirection="Horizontal" RepeatLayout="Table">
        <asp:ListItem Text="*Answer 1*" Value="Incorrect 1" />
        <asp:ListItem Text="*Answer 2*" Value="Correct" />
        <asp:ListItem Text="*Answer 3*" Value="I" />
        <asp:ListItem Text="*Answer 4*" Value="4" />
    </asp:RadioButtonList>
    <div>
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="Q6requiredvalidator" runat="server" Display="Dynamic" ControlToValidate="RadioButtonList6" CssClass="text-danger" EnableClientScript="True" ErrorMessage="Ensure question 6 is completed"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
    </div>
    <asp:Label ID="QLabel7" runat="server" Text="Question 7"></asp:Label>
    <asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList7" runat="server"
        RepeatDirection="Horizontal" RepeatLayout="Table">
        <asp:ListItem Text="*Answer 1*" Value="Incorrect 1" />
        <asp:ListItem Text="*Answer 2*" Value="Correct" />
        <asp:ListItem Text="*Answer 3*" Value="I" />
        <asp:ListItem Text="*Answer 4*" Value="4" />
    </asp:RadioButtonList>
    <div>
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="Q7requiredvalidator" runat="server" Display="Dynamic" ControlToValidate="RadioButtonList7" CssClass="text-danger" EnableClientScript="True" ErrorMessage="Ensure question 7 is completed"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
    </div>
    <asp:Label ID="QLabel8" runat="server" Text="Question 8"></asp:Label>
    <asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList8" runat="server"
        RepeatDirection="Horizontal" RepeatLayout="Table">
        <asp:ListItem Text="*Answer 1*" Value="Incorrect 1" />
        <asp:ListItem Text="*Answer 2*" Value="Correct" />
        <asp:ListItem Text="*Answer 3*" Value="I" />
        <asp:ListItem Text="*Answer 4*" Value="4" />
    </asp:RadioButtonList>
    <div>
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="Q8requiredvalidator" runat="server" Display="Dynamic" ControlToValidate="RadioButtonList8" CssClass="text-danger" EnableClientScript="True" ErrorMessage="Ensure question 8 is completed"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
    </div>
    <asp:Label ID="QLabel9" runat="server" Text="Question 9"></asp:Label>
    <asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList9" runat="server"
        RepeatDirection="Horizontal" RepeatLayout="Table">
        <asp:ListItem Text="*Answer 1*" Value="Incorrect 1" />
        <asp:ListItem Text="*Answer 2*" Value="Correct" />
        <asp:ListItem Text="*Answer 3*" Value="I" />
        <asp:ListItem Text="*Answer 4*" Value="4" />
    </asp:RadioButtonList>
    <div>
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="Q9requiredvalidator" runat="server" Display="Dynamic" ControlToValidate="RadioButtonList9" CssClass="text-danger" EnableClientScript="True" ErrorMessage="Ensure question 9 is completed"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
    </div>
    <asp:Label ID="QLabel10" runat="server" Text="Question 10"></asp:Label>
    <asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList10" runat="server"
        RepeatDirection="Horizontal" RepeatLayout="Table">
        <asp:ListItem Text="*Answer 1*" Value="Incorrect 1" />
        <asp:ListItem Text="*Answer 2*" Value="Correct" />
        <asp:ListItem Text="*Answer 3*" Value="I" />
        <asp:ListItem Text="*Answer 4*" Value="4" />
    </asp:RadioButtonList>
    <div>
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="Q10requiredvalidator" runat="server" Display="Dynamic" ControlToValidate="RadioButtonList10" CssClass="text-danger" EnableClientScript="True" ErrorMessage="Ensure question 10 is completed"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
    </div>
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Submit Final Answers" OnClick="Submit_Click" Visible="true" />

    <script runat="server">
        protected void Submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!this.IsValid)
                return;
            int score = 0;
            List<RadioButtonList> list = new List<RadioButtonList>() { RadioButtonList1, RadioButtonList2, RadioButtonList3, RadioButtonList4, RadioButtonList5, RadioButtonList6, RadioButtonList7, RadioButtonList8, RadioButtonList9, RadioButtonList10 };
            foreach (var element in list)
            {
                if (element.SelectedValue == "Correct")
                {
                    score++;
                }

            }
            Response.Write("you scored: " + score);
            Button1.Visible = false;
        }
    </script>
    <script runat="server">

    </script>

</asp:Content>
```

My default connection string in `web.config`:

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-ComputingProjectwh-20170404101246.mdf;Initial Catalog=aspnet-ComputingProjectwh-20170404101246;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

Comment: your question is not clear. I have not understand so much but may be this can help. Just go to sql server and create a new table. then using sessions you can save the username and his score

Comment: Why are you making a new table per user? Why not just store the user's name or ID alongside their responses in a single table?

Comment: each time creating a new table is not a good approach. then what is benefit of using database when creating so many tables.

Comment: i will only create one table i just dont really know where to go from where i am. sorry if i was not clear

Comment: The solution to your question is an entire blog. You better do google around  this.

Comment: @DanielTurville then you really need to google it or see video tutorials to know how to do it. i